# CopyFiles using IFileOperation (C++)

Tags: c++

I want to copy multiple files using IFileOperation.
Copy a single file is not a problem like this example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

My Problem is that I don't find a way to copy multiple files like *.txt.
I have tried using SHCreateShellItemArrayFromIDLists, like this snippet:

```
    IShellItem *psiTo = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = SHCreateItemFromParsingName( csTarget, NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&psiTo) );
    LPCITEMIDLIST pidlFiles = ILCreateFromPath(csSource);
    UINT count = sizeof(pidlFiles);
    IShellItemArray* psiaFiles = NULL;
    hr = SHCreateShellItemArrayFromIDLists(count, &pidlFiles, &psiaFiles);
    hr = pfo->CopyItems(psiaFiles, psiTo);
    hr = pfo->PerformOperations();
```

A other way is to use SHCreateShellItemArray, like this:

```
LPCITEMIDLIST pidlParent = ILCreateFromPath(_T("C:\\"));
LPCITEMIDLIST pidlChild = ILCreateFromPath(_T("C:\\Temp\\*.txt"));
HRESULT hr = SHCreateShellItemArray(pidlParent, NULL, 1, &pidlChild, &psiaFiles);
hr = pfo->CopyItems(psiaFiles, psiTo);
hr = pfo->PerformOperations();
```

I tried different way but almost I get E_INVALIDIDARG or ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND.
Whats wrong?

Comment: Make sure you double backslash before the `*` in `pidlChild`?

Comment: Yes, thats not the problem

Answer (score 1):

`ILCreateFromPath` doesn't take wildcards. Couldn't, since it returns a single `PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE`.

The easiest solution is to enumerate all files manually `FindFirstFile(*.txt)`, call `CopyItem` on each result, and then call `PerformOperations` once at the end.

As usual, the older Windows functions are better. `SHFileOperation` is ten times simpler and more capable to boot: it does support wildcards directly.